# Azure Virtual Machine CPU Cores Limit

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal

When I try to deploy a new virtual machine in my Azure portal I get the following error at deployment time.

> Deployment to resource group 'Testing' failed. Additional  details
>   from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least  one resource
>   deployment operation failed. Please list  deployment operations for
>   details. Please see  https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
>   (Code:  DeploymentFaiIed) Operation results in exceeding quota limits 
>   of Core. Maximum allowed: 20, Current in use: 24, Additional 
>   requested: 4. (Code: OperationNotAIIowed)

Is there a way to work around this issue please? Or can the maximum allowed cores be increased?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default per Azure subscription there is a soft quota limit on virtual machine CPU cores of 20.

This can be increased by raising a Help and Support request within the portal using the predefined quota limitation options to get the current amount of CPU cores available increased.

Source: http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/06/azure-virual-machine-cpu-cores-quota/

[image]

Once submitted this will be reviewed and approved by the support team and your limit set.

If the request is for a reasonable amount this shouldn't take long to action.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the limit, do you know?

Comment: the default for Enterprise Agreement subscriptions is 350.